# Is the following code a good solution for a multi-threaded increment counter and print?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdatomic

Can you give you your opinion, please?
What would you do differently?
I mean, do you think it would be better if I have done it with std::task or std::mutex, std::condition_variable, etc?
I an overkill to control the threads with 2 flags?

```
std::atomic<int> counter = { 0 };
std::atomic<bool> switchFlag = { false };
std::atomic<bool> finished = { false };
constexpr int MAX_NUM = 10;

void increment(){
    while (!finished.load()){
        if (!switchFlag.load()){
            std::cout << "incremented to =" << ++counter << '\n';
            switchFlag.store(true);
        }
    }
}

void print(){
    while (!finished.load()) {
        if (switchFlag.load()){
            std::cout << "counter=" << counter.load() << '\n';
            if (counter.load() >= MAX_NUM)
                finished.store(true);

            switchFlag.store(false);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    auto t1 = std::thread(increment);
    auto t2 = std::thread(print);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This approach will burn 100% of two CPU cores for the duration of its run, which seems inefficient.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can't use semaphores?

Comment: FWIW, the code doesn't need to explicitly call `.load()`. `atomic<bool>` has an implicit conversion to `bool` which will do that load when `finished` or `switchFlag` is used in a boolean context, e.g., `if(finished)` or `if (!finished)`.

Comment: I was trying to avoid using sleep

Comment: @anc If you want one thread to wait for another thread to do something, don't use `sleep`. You have condition variable for precisely that. If everyone else does something a particular way, there's probably a reason. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is, to be blunt, unbelievably awful on typical, realistic hardware. The most obvious problem is this:

Look at the thread in `increment`. Until `print` runs, the `if` will be `false` and the `while` will be true. To branch prediction will begin becoming firmly convinced that the `if` will be `false`.

Then, when the `print` thread sets `switchFlag` to `false` and you need `increment` to execute as quickly as possible because the other thread is going to be waiting for it, you take the worst mispredicted branch imaginable.

So at the very instant where it is is the most critical that you execute as quickly as possible, you encounter the very worst performance the processor can give you, blowing out all the pipelines with a mispredicted branch.

I would strongly urge you not to try to compose complex operations out of primitive operations like atomic loads and stores. Doing so requires deep platform expertise. Use high-level functions (like mutexes and condition variables) for high-level operations (like waiting).

But there's never any good way to implement two threads that need to alternate execution. For any case where two threads can't ever concurrently make forward progress, there's no good reason to have two threads.

Comment: You could also note that default load and store operations on atomics are fairly slow - since they imply a strong type of synchronization.

Comment: Thanks, David, this exactly what I was expecting to hear. Then what would you suggest to me?

Comment: @anc It depends exactly what you're trying to do. If you have two tasks that can never make forward progress at the same time, don't use two threads. If you need one thread to wait for another to finish doing something, use a condition variable. If you just need mutual exclusion, use a mutex.